# C# Dictionary Error - An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dictionary

I'm inserting a unique `ID[KEY]` in a dictionary with its corresponding `time[VALUE]`.
I have only unique values in the ID column but i get the below error

> *"An item with the same key has already been added"*

```
for (int j = 0; j < pro1.Count; j++)
{

  string startend = "Select Id, CStart, CEnd from MBA1 where Channel='" + mbaChannel[allchan] + "' and Product='" + pro[allpro] + "' and ProgDate='" + pro1[j] + "'";
  SqlCommand dat = new SqlCommand(startend, conn);
  SqlDataReader datrdr = dat.ExecuteReader();
  while (datrdr.Read())
  {
      start.Add(datrdr["Id"].ToString(), datrdr.GetDateTime(1));
      end.Add(datrdr["Id"].ToString(), datrdr.GetDateTime(2));

  }
  datrdr.Close();
```

I'm sure there is no duplicate in my `ID` column. Please help!

Comment: maybe Dictionaries are not empty when you start reading?

Comment: Good formatting is always your friend..

Comment: how can you be so sure of this? Did you call yourDict.ContainsKey() to check this?

Comment: Not much we can help with... It won't lie, at some point you must be adding a duplicate key.

Comment: Debug your code, is faster and easy, step by step.

Comment: Aside from the things already mentioned, you should refactor your SQL code to take in paramters. At the moment you're possibly vunerable to SQL injection attacks, even if the values aren't directly coming from the user.

Answer (score 1):

Your query and dictionary update are in a loop. If there are no duplicate values in the `Id` column, then your query is returning at least 1 row in two different queries (different values of `j` in your example).

Answer (score 1):

You are running your query pro1.Count times.  If pro1.Count > 1, you will try to put duplicate items in your dictionary.